# Volley converts BigInteger value to Exponential value

Tags: java, android, android-volley, biginteger

I am facing a strange issue while accessing an API. 
The API should respond with a BigInteger value like `17724883XXXXXXXX03039051626691` but it automatically converts to an exponential value `1.77248XXXXXXXXXX3E30`. 
I tried the same request in POSTMAN and iOS both returns BigInteger value.

So I tried to convert the Exponential value to BigInteger with the below code.

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("17724883XXXXXXXX03039051626691");
```

But it failed to return exact value. The results given below.

```
BD Plain String BigDecimal: 17724883XXXXXXXXXX0000000000000
Engineering String :1.7724XXXXXXXXXX33E+30
String value :1.7724XXXXXXXXXX3E+30
abs :1.7724XXXXXXXXXXX3E+30
double value :1.7724XXXXXXXXXX3E30
```

Please let me know if anyone faced this kind of issue before. Is this a volley issue?

Comment: Show us what you exactly get from the API and in which data structure you see the double value.

Comment: "...but **it** automatically converts..."  What specifically do you mean by "it"?

Comment: The first place where I am getting the response is an Exponential value instead of BigInteger. the same request in POST man iOS app it is a BigInteger. So I think volley converts it to Exponential value from the BigInteger.

Comment: could anyone tell me JsonRequest's  PROTOCOL_CHARSET utf-8 any hand in this ? I changed utf-16 and no difference

Comment: The JsonObject method (the first place where we get the response) itself convert the value\n

Comment: @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }